# Reference to multiple labels with \cref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I need to refer to seven figures which are not continuous in sequence (say figures 5.3b, 5.3d, 5.3f, 5.4b, 5.4d, 5.5b, 5.5d).

When I am using

```
\cref{5-3-b,5-3-d,,5-3-f,5-4-b,5-4-d,5-5-b,,5-5-d}
```

It prints

> Figures 5.3b to 5.5b, 5.3d to 5.5d and 5.3f)

Note: the figures are from three different subfigures.

I do not want those "to" in between. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Please do provide a full minimal example document that demonstrates the problem. The double-comma in @Mico's answer merely works-around the issue. What you're seeing could be a bug, or it could be a misunderstanding of what `cleveref` does, but without a ME it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something very odd seems to be going on in your document, as `cleveref` does not normally engage in the type of behavior you say is occurring. How are the figures and subfigures constructed in your document? Please consider posting a full MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

At any rate, the following should work for your setup:

```
\cref{5-3-b,,5-3-d,,5-3-f,,5-4-b,,5-4-d,,5-5-b,,5-5-d}
```

See section 5, entitled "Sorting and compressing", of the [package's user guide](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) for an explanation of how the double comma constructs work.

---

Here's an MWE (minimum working example), which demonstrates that both `\cref{5-3-b,5-3-d,5-3-f,5-4-b,5-4-d,5-5-b,5-5-d}` and `\cref{5-3-b,,5-3-d,,5-3-f,,5-4-b,,5-4-d,,5-5-b,,5-5-d}` produce the same output if normal setup rules are obeyed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment and counter
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{5}
\setcounter{figure}{2}

\cref{5-3-b,5-3-d,5-3-f,5-4-b,5-4-d,5-5-b,5-5-d}

\cref{5-3-b,,5-3-d,,5-3-f,,5-4-b,,5-4-d,,5-5-b,,5-5-d}

% the following code is deliberately minimalist
\refstepcounter{figure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-3-b}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-3-d}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-3-f}

\refstepcounter{figure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-4-b}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-4-d}

\refstepcounter{figure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-5-b}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{5-5-d}

\end{document}
```